# How to index a status ( flag ) field

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-performance

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `brand` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shown` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_products_brandId_idx` (`brand`),
  KEY `pk_products_shown` (`shown`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_products_brandId` FOREIGN KEY (`brand`) REFERENCES `brands` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_products_categoryId` FOREIGN KEY (`category`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have this "shown" fields, which I use to mark deleted records (if the user deletes a record, it's not deleted; these fields are set to value 0).

So all my queries more or less looks like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM products WHERE brand = 1 AND shown = 1"
```

but if I explain that in MySQL/oracle Workbench it says full table scan. Obviously it makes sense, since 99% of my DB records will have shown = 1, but brand has an index as well.

here is the explain outputed by the workbench

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "2.40"
    },
    "table": {
      "table_name": "products",
      "access_type": "ALL",
      "possible_keys": [
        "fk_products_brandId_idx",
        "pk_products_shown"
      ],
      "rows_examined_per_scan": 7,
      "rows_produced_per_join": 2,
      "filtered": "40.82",
      "cost_info": {
        "read_cost": "1.83",
        "eval_cost": "0.57",
        "prefix_cost": "2.40",
        "data_read_per_join": "6K"
      },
      "used_columns": [
        "id",
        "name_bg",
        "name_en",
        "category",
        "weight",
        "width",
        "length",
        "height",
        "brand",
        "availability",
        "text_bg",
        "text_en",
        "sold",
        "price",
        "price_retail",
        "linked_products",
        "created_at",
        "created_by",
        "updated_at",
        "updated_by",
        "shown"
      ],
      "attached_condition": "((`whatever`.`products`.`shown` = 1) and (`whatever`.`products`.`brand` = 18))"
    }
  }
}
```

Is my logic wrong, or my shown index has be amended somehow so normal queries wont do a full table scan ?

mysql 5.7

Comment: Since the table seems to have only 7 rows, it does not matter whether it it is using the index.  Come back when you have 100 rows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a compound index on `(brand, shown)`. That index will accelerate queries with filters on `brand = constant AND shown=1` as well as just `brand=constant`.

```
ALTER TABLE products ADD INDEX brand_shown (brand, shown);
```

This index also accelerates queries of the form

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE brand >= 1 AND brand <=10 AND shown = 1;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE brand BETWEEN 1 AND 10 AND shown = 1;
```

Doing a good job of indexing takes some knowledge. Reading https://use-the-index-luke.com/ is an excellent way to learn.

MySQL is probably doing a full table scan becasue the cardinality -- the number of distinct values -- of `shown` is very low. So it guesses that a table scan will be cheaper than trying to figure out how to get the data from an index.

If you can amend your query to

```
SELECT name FROM products WHERE brand = constant AND shown = 1
```

then add `name` to the index, you'll have [a so-called *covering index*](http://www.unofficialmysqlguide.com/covering-indexes.html). That will allow MySQL to satisfy your query solely by doing a range scan on the index, and will be quite fast.

```
ALTER TABLE products ADD INDEX brand_shown_name (brand, shown, name);
```

**Pro tip** Avoid `SELECT *` in queries where performance is an issue. Instead, list the columns you need. MySQL may be able to apply some optimizations (like the covering index optimization) when you do that.

**Pro tip 2** Avoid creating indexes just for good measure. Create the ones you actually need for queries (or for enforcing uniqueness).  Extra indexes take space and slow down INSERT and UPDATE operations.

Comment: "Create a compound index on (brand, shown). That index will accelerate queries with filters on brand = constant AND shown=1 as well as just brand=constant." To add to that statement `WHERE brand > 0 AND shown = 1` if you need all brands with the shown = 1 this query can also make use off the brand_shown index.

Comment: it also might help to run ANALYZE [table] (note this query locks the table also InnoDB tables) once in a while.. it updates the index stats (cardinality) and helps the optimizer to pick a more optimal plan... Please also note ANALYZE [table] only really helps when running alot of bulk inserts or bulk updates on the table.

Comment: i see. I wonder if I add category to the pull aswell. for ex:  
brand_cat_shown_inedex, and run the query without specifying the category, does this make sense ?

Comment: If you do `WHERE category = constant` as well as your other filters, putting the category in the index will help retrieval time. If all you want is to `SELECT category`, the arguments applying to covering indexes apply. You should read about covering indexes.

Comment: @O.Jones -- you have the index backwards for those queries.  Use `INDEX(shown, brand)` since `shown is tested with `=`.  See this for more discussion or order of columns in `INDEX`:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: @RaymondNijland - `ANALYZE` is so rarely useful that I advise against running it except in very rare cases and very infrequently.